# How to enable IMAP PHP extension on AWS EC2 instance Amazon Linux 2023?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, fedora, imap

This question is related with the following one: [How to enable IMAP php extension on aws EC2 instance](https://serverfault.com/questions/1032506/how-to-enable-imap-php-extension-on-aws-ec2-instance) but they are completely different.

I use **PHP 8.1** and **Amazon Linux 2023**, this version does not have "amazon-linux-extras", so I can´t install it.

In the following link we can see the list of packages, if we filter by "php8.1" we will see that "php8.1-imap" does not exist: [All the packages AL2023](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/release-notes/all-packages-AL2023.2.html)

I think I need to run the following command: `sudo yum install libc-client-devel uw-imap-static openssl-devel -y` but only "openssl-devel" is part of the list of packages of AL2023, I have no idea how to install it.

Comment: Install Amazon Linux Extras read https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/ec2-install-extras-library-software or https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/amazon-linux-ami-basics.html#extras-library

Comment: those links are to Amazon Linux 2. My question is about Amazon Linux 2023

Comment: I know, take a snapshot then give it a shot anyway. If it doesn't work I suspect getting amazon-linux-extras or the AL 2023 equivalent working is a good approach. I haven't used AL2023 yet, not sure how different it is from AL2

Answer (score 0):

Enabling the IMAP PHP extension on Amazon Linux 2023, which does not support amazon-linux-extras, involves a few steps.

Here are three specific things to try:

**Install Development Tools:** You'll likely need development tools to compile the IMAP extension from source. This can be done using the command:

```
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

**Compile the IMAP Extension from Source:** The steps typically include navigating to the `php/ext/imap` directory within the PHP source code and then using `phpize`, `./configure`, and `make` to compile the extension.

**Configuration:** After compiling the IMAP extension, you will need to configure PHP to use the new extension. This involves adding the `extension=imap.so` line to your `php.ini` file or a specific `*.ini` file within the `conf.d` directory. Restarting the web server or the PHP-FPM service will be necessary to apply the changes. On Amazon Linux, you might use:

```
sudo nano /etc/php.d/30-imap.ini
```

And add:

```
extension=imap
```

Then restart your HTTP server or PHP-FPM process​​.

Comment: The last step is done, but I would love if you include step by step of the step 2, I mean "Compile the IMAP Extension from Source"